# Call getPackageName() early in the application lifecycle

Tags: android

I need to call `getPackageName` early in the application lifecycle. I tried to call it in the `Application` constructor only to see that it throws `NullPointerException`. I had a look at the Android source code and found [that](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Instrumentation.java#992) Android calls the internal `attach` method which in turn calls the **documented** protected `attachBaseContext` method. Once I moved my code from the constructor into `attachBaseContext` everything works as expected.

**Question**: is it good idea to assume `attachBaseContext` method as a kind of extension to the `Application` constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just **pacakageName** I would suggest to use `BuildConfig#APPLICATION_ID`, because it is static variable and doesn't require waiting for application initialization. Difference between package name and application id you can find [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename).

If you anyway need some entry point to application, IMHO it seems to be a good idea to use `attachBaseContext(Context c)` method, because:

- It might be called only once (as constructor).
- It is the first place in Application where you can get application context